# How can I change my checking for winner method in my tictactoe game

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I have a so far working TicTacToe game but my checking for a winner method "hasPlayerWon" doesnt work.Everytime one player makes a move it already gives me out a winner.

I tried to involve numRows and numColumns instead of writing "i++" etc. but it also didnt work.

```
private boolean hasPlayerWon() {
        boolean winner = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
                {
                    if (this.board[i][j] == PLAYER_A && this.board[i++][j++] == PLAYER_A) {
                        System.out.println("Player A has won");
                    }
                    if (this.board[i][j] == PLAYER_A && this.board[i++][j] == PLAYER_A) {
                        System.out.println("Player A has won");
                    }
                    if (this.board[i][j] == PLAYER_A && this.board[i][j++] == PLAYER_A) {
                        System.out.println("Player A has won");
                    }
                        if (this.board[i][j] == PLAYER_B && this.board[i++][j++] == PLAYER_B) {
                            System.out.println("Player B has won");
                        }
                    if (this.board[i][j] == PLAYER_B && this.board[i++][j] == PLAYER_B) {
                        System.out.println("Player B has won");
                    }
                    if (this.board[i][j] == PLAYER_B && this.board[i][j++] == PLAYER_B) {
                        System.out.println("Player B has won");
                    }

                    }
                }
            }

         return winner;

    }
```

Of course I expect it to give me out the winner after one has properly filled either the diagonal horizontal or vertical with his sign. But it prints me out the result after just one input. 1 stands for the "X" of Player A and a 2 for the "O" of Player B. So I want to check if in either the horizontal,vertical or diagonal either a 1 or 2 is filled in.

The output I get:

```
Move: 0
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 

Turn for Player1
Select a rowposition between 0 and 4
1
Select a columnposition between 0 and 4
1
Move: 1
0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 

Player A has won
Turn for Player2
Select a rowposition between 0 and 4
```

Comment: Each time, you test only two values of your array. I think you should test 4 of them, since you have to make a line of four to win (I suppose as your board is a 4x4). Then for the `i++` instruction, the i value is evaluated before the incrementation, this is why you have a winner at the first move. Even if your code will not work, use `++i` if you want to increment before the evaluation

Comment: I changed all the "i++" and "j++" to "++i" and "++j". But now I get an ArrayIndexoutofBoundsException after the second Player has done his turn.

Comment: Because you don't have to increment your indexes. Sorry I forget to tell you about this. When you evaluate your condition, if you increment your index `i` or `j`, it will be incremented for each condition that you want to test. So you should not increment `i` but just evaluate something like `this.board[i + 1][j]`. Like this, the value of `i` will not change

Comment: But I have a flexible board. Like the size of it, if 4x4, or 7x7 or whatever is implemented in the TicTacToe class itself and will be given over in my main class. so I kind of need to implement it to make i + x until it reached the max?

Answer (score 0):

```
//check if all the data across the row is the same player
for(int row=0; row<4, row++){
 int col=0;

//Check if player A has won 
 if(this.board[row][col++] == PLAYER_A && this.board[row][col++] == PLAYER_A && 
    this.board[row][col++] == PLAYER_A && this.board[row][col++] == PLAYER_A)
      System.out.println("Player A has won");

 //reset col to 0
    col=0;

 //Check if player B has won 
  else if(this.board[i][col++] == PLAYER_B && this.board[i][col++] == PLAYER_B && 
    this.board[i][col++] == PLAYER_B && this.board[i][col++] == PLAYER_B)
      System.out.println("Player B has won");


}

//check if all the data across the column is the same player
for(int col=0; col<4, col++){
 int row=0;

//Check if player A has won 
 if(this.board[row++][col] == PLAYER_A && this.board[row++][col]  == PLAYER_A && 
    this.board[row++][col] == PLAYER_A && this.board[row++][col]  == PLAYER_A)
      System.out.println("Player A has won");

   reset the row to 0
   col=0;

 //Check if player B has won 
else if(this.board[row++][col] == PLAYER_B && this.board[row++][col] == PLAYER_B && 
       this.board[row++][col] == PLAYER_B && this.board[row++][col] == PLAYER_B)
      System.out.println("Player B has won");
 }

 //check if the diagonals all have the same board

    int row =0;
    int col =0;

 //check from the top left to bottom right
 //Player A
  if(this.board[row++][col++] == PLAYER_A && this.board[row++][col++]  == PLAYER_A && 
  this.board[row++][col++] == PLAYER_A && this.board[row++][col++]  == PLAYER_A)
      System.out.println("Player A has won");
  //Player B
  if(this.board[row++][col++] == PLAYER_B && this.board[row++][col++]  == PLAYER_B && 
    this.board[row++][col++] == PLAYER_B && this.board[row++][col++]  == PLAYER_B)
      System.out.println("Player B has won");

  row=0;
  col=3;
  //check from the top right to bottom left
  //Player A
  if(this.board[row++][col--] == PLAYER_A && this.board[row++][col--]  == PLAYER_A && 
 this.board[row++][col--] == PLAYER_A && this.board[row++][col--]  == PLAYER_A)
      System.out.println("Player A has won");
 //Player B
  if(this.board[row++][col--] == PLAYER_B && this.board[row++][col--]  == PLAYER_B && 
 this.board[row++][col--] == PLAYER_B && this.board[row++][col--]  == PLAYER_B)
      System.out.println("Player B has won");
```

Comment: This is a long process of finding the solution, It is, however, a sure way of getting the goals as it considers all the combinations required for a win. You can add a boolean variable that is updated when there is a win, in the lower loops you can check if a win has already been obtained hence not run the code to check for a win

Comment: Weird, this one doesnt work for me at all...my main class doesnt even get to the point of checking if there is a winner or not with this one. But my numRows and numColumns is also final, so instead of your row I used i and instead of your col I used j, and iterated i< numrows and the j < numcolumns, but didnt work..